# Why does f# mutate an immutable variable without warning or error?

Tags: f#, f#-data

The following script mutates the immutable variable jar without errors or warnings.
Is this a bug? Or a bug in my understanding?

Please explain why I don't need to use the mutable keyword.

aside: The cookieContainer argument to FSharp.Data.Http.RequestString is not marked as mutable in the definition: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data/blob/134a08cda3acb8e746bb25d03692d90ee5caabab/src/Net/Http.fs

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll";;
#r "nuget:FSharp.Data";; 

open FSharp.Data

let url="http://www.google.com"
let uri=System.Uri(url)

// no mutable keyword here
let jar=System.Net.CookieContainer()

// Count is 0
printf $"Pre-request cookie count is: {jar.GetCookies(uri).Count}\n"

let r = Http.RequestString(url, cookieContainer=jar) 

// Count is 1
printf $"Post-request cookie count is: {jar.GetCookies(uri).Count}\n"
```

#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll";;
#r "nuget:FSharp.Data";;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two distinct concepts related to mutatation in F#:

- **Mutable variables**, which are variables that can change value. They are defined using `let mutable` and you change the value using `<-` (which is not possible if the variable is not mutable).
- **Mutable objects** which are just .NET objects that have some mutable state that can be changed by invoking a method on the object. Those are instances of normal C#-style classes.

If you define an *immutable variable* that is a reference to a *mutable object*, the object can still be mutated. The fact that the variable is immutable does not prevent that from happening. That is what's happening in your case.

Like there are immutable variables, there are also immutable objects (or values). This includes F# data types like records and discriminated unions. However, the fact whether an object is mutable or not is not tracked in the language - so this is something you do not see in any obvious way.

In well-designed F# code, most of your own objects will be immutable, but most of the .NET objects you are using (to access the functionality provided by .NET) will be mutable - because that's how .NET is designed.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, this is very clear.